# Пример запроса Twitter Api android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-api

Не могу найти ни один пример запроса Twitter Api android. Если кто может - предоставьте пример выполнения такого запроса в android. Cпасибо.

Comment: Неужели в доке нет примеров?

Comment: Вот вам дока и пример: https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/access-rest-api.html

Comment: Там сложновато что-то )

Comment: Поясните что именно сложно

Comment: Можете тут прикрепить пример кода с запросом и чуточку объяснить его ?

Comment: Например, я хочу получить список читателей в твиттере. Как приблизительно должен выглядеть запрос ?